# Перезагрузить страницу средствами php

Tags: ajax, php

Добрый день!

Я пишу систему авторизации, хотелось бы ее сделать без перезагрузки страницы, на ajax.

**файл: login.php**
Есть два поля ввода - емаил и пароль.
Кнопка - ок.
При нажатии на кнопку идет ajax запрос, где проверяется, правильно ли пользователь ввел логин и пароль.

Если неправильно - сразу же вывожу ошибку, если правильно - необходимо загрузить (переадресовать) страницу **index.php**.

Как это сделать, понятия не имею.

Answer (score 3):

```
header ('Location');
header ('Refresh');
```

Answer (score 1):

Проще некуда - если авторизация успешна, то вызвать в JS `window.location = '/index.php';`.

Comment: Как вызвать JS через PHP?

Comment: Зачем так?  
Если авторизовал верно, то возвращай, например, слово `OK`. На JS проверяешь - ОК ли? Если да - перенаправляешь куда надо на JS.  
Лучше, конечно, через JSON.